# What does "Local IT Costs" refer to in the UK/Europe?

Tags: taxes

I'm filling out an year end report form and there is a field for `Local IT costs`. I was looking through the internet, but I can't find any explanation of what **exactly** does this field supposed to be referring to?

What is `Local IT costs` supposed to refer to? Is it costs related to your `ISP` / `Hardware repairs` / `local IT guy who comes to install software on your machine` ?

Comment: What kind of "report"? Knowing the context would help to know if IT means Information Technology or something else. Local Income Tax?

Comment: It's an year end expenses report.

Comment: `year end expenses report` for what ? Ltd company ? Self employment ?

Comment: Okay - who is the form sent to? Do they have instructions on how to fill out the form or anyone you can contact to get an answer? If it's not a widely used form like a tax return then your guess is as good as ours.